# tkz-euclide "Undefined control sequence"

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide, undefined

I've been trying to practice tkz-euclide by working through the documentation's examples. But I've been getting errors. Here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{beton}
\usepackage{euler}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,4/0/B}
    \tkzDrawLine[red](A,B)
    \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=1.2](A,B)
    \tkzGetPoint{P}
    \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=-0.2](A,B)
    \tkzGetPoint{R}
    \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=0.5](A,B)
    \tkzGetPoint{S}
    \tkzLabelPoint[above](P){pos=$1.2$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[above](R){pos=$-.2$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[above](S){pos=$.5$}
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,P,R,S)
    \tkzLabelPoints[](A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I try to compile this I get this error despite the command being listed and used in the documentation:

```
Undefined control sequence. [\tkzDefPointOnLine]
```

I've checked similar questions, but they all say to add usetkzobj{all} and yet the current README of the package says this is not required. Furthermore, when I do add it in, I get this:

```
I can't find file `tkz-obj-angles.tex'. [\usetkzobj{all}]
```

What's going on?

Comment: It appears here (page 37): http://ctan.dcc.uchile.cl/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-euclide/doc/TKZdoc-euclide.pdf

Comment: Are you sure you are using the latest version of  `tkz-euclide` ? I just managed to compile it and get the expected image

Comment: I'm not so sure what version I have. I'm using the version I suppose that came with the distro TeXlive that I downloaded a couple weeks ago.

Comment: I agree with @EduardoAlvesdaSilva. I had an older version installed, with which I could reproduce the error. But this older version did not have `\tkzDefPointOnLine` in its manual. Once I updated (with the TeXLive update manager), the error disappeared and the command was in the updated manual.

Comment: I did the same and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry  I'm coming in after the fight. Actually the version is 3.02 and in several days it will be 3.03 with better documentation and some minor changes. `\tkzDefPointOnLine` is only on the last update . If you have a problem, do not hesitate to contact me with the address indicated on the documentation. Don't forget to update tkz-base at the same time!

Comment: @EduardoAlvesdaSilva Maybe you or Alain could write an official answer? BTW, thanks for the edit!

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat done! And you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to using an old version of `tkz-euclide` (check [Allain Matthes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3144/alain-matthes) comment on the question for more details)

With the correct version, you should get the following image:

[image]